# Short key to run a binary in dired-mode

Tags: dired

In dired-mode I can type `!` to use the selected file as an argument for a command. For instance, if I type `! rm <RET>` it will run the command `rm filename`.

What I wanted is a short-key to run the file (if it is executable). Let's say I have this short-key mapped to `@`. Then I would type `@ arg <RET>` and it would run the selected file with the given argument, i.e., `./filename arg`.

Comment: Are you aware that `dired-smart-shell-command` offers you the file below point as default?  If you are at an executable file in a dired buffer press `M-!` and `<down>`. The file at point is inserted in the minibuffer. That is almost what you want. There are two things that would be better. 1st) If a space would be appended to the file name 2nd) If point would be placed at the end of the default input.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this. It is certainly helpful. But inserting the `./` still annoys me a little.

Comment: The following advice adds the dot in the second default value: `(defun my-add-shell-commands-filter-ret (ret) (cons (car ret) (cons (concat "./" (car ret)) (cdr ret)))) (advice-add 'minibuffer-default-add-shell-commands :filter-return #'my-add-shell-commands-filter-ret)`

Comment: @Tobias I tried this advice but it doesn't have any effect in my emacs 24.